# Multiple Name input in JOptionPane

Tags: java, joptionpane

I'm trying to create a for loop that allows the user to enter multiple player names (up to 6) and store each player name in a variable (playerone, playertwo etc;) and in between each prompt for a name the user should be asked if they would like to enter another player's name. I have written the for loop but can't figure how to assign each input to a string variable. If the user selects No in the dialog, it should break the for loop.

```
if (text.equals(play)) {
    {
        {
            String Playerone = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Player 1:");
            textArea.append("Player 1: " + Playerone);

            for (i = 2; i <= 6; i++) {
                int n2 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Enter another player?", "",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

                if (n2 == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Player " + i + "\n");
                    textArea.append("Player " + i + ":" + "\n");

                }
                if (n2 == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw It is over 500 lines of code this isn't very practical

Answer (score 0):

```
if (n2 == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Player " + i + "\n");
    textArea.append("Player " + i + ":" + "\n");

}else 
if (n2 == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
    break;
}
```

replace your ifs in the for loop with this and it should work. you can't have dynamic variable names. use any type of list or array for that

Comment: What is the best way then of assigning each input to a variable name (playerone, playertwo etc;) as each username will have to be assigned to one of these variables

Comment: first you can store them in an array and then you have to initialize a variable for each player, so you have x lines at the end. BUT it is much better to use an array throughout your program

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `break` operator to out of loop.

Use a `ArrayList` to store all names in a variable .

Java `ArrayList` class uses a dynamic array for storing the elements.

```
ArrayList<String> userNames=new ArrayList<String>

if (n2 == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    String playerName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Player " + i + ":");
    userNames.add(playerName);
}else if(n2 == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){ 
    break;
 }
```

Iterate `ArrayList` in java

```
int i=1; 
for(String name:userNames){
    System.out.println("Player"+i+" : "+name);
    i+=1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`JOptionPane.showInputDialog` returns a string when the user presses ok, otherwise it will return null.

"I have written the for loop but can't figure how to assign each input to a string variable"

```
String Playerone = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Player 1:" );
```

I can see you know how to assign each value to a string variable, don't be unsure of your capabilities, unless you copied that code somewhere without understanding it. Since we have multiple players, I'm using a string array to store the input.

To answer your second question, to break out of your loop, simply type `break;`

In conclusion, we should have something like this:

```
String Playerone = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Player 1:" );
textArea.append("Player 1: " + Playerone);

String[] playernames = new String[5];

for(i=2; i<=6;i++) {

    int n2 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Enter another player?" ,"",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

    if(n2 == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
         playernames[i-2] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Player "+ i + "\n");
         textArea.append("Player " + i + ":" + "\n" );


    }
    else if(n2 == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
           break;

    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for that help. when I use this, after I input the 6th player it seems to close the program, is there a way to stop this?

Comment: Ah yes. Thank you. Is it possible to assign elements of the array to variables? for example playernames[1] to 'Playertwo'

Comment: I figured it out with `String playertwo = playernames[0];`